# Should I store important Blu-ray discs vacuum packed with a silica gel bag to ensure they will work 10 to 20 years from now?

Tags: blu-ray, lifespan

If I want to store a Blu-ray discs and hope they still work in 10 to 20 years, should I vacuum pack it with some silica gel?

My idea would be to put it into a paper disc storage sleeve, put that sleeve and a silica gel bag (say 3g) into a vacuum bag, apply a vacuum and then store it in a dark place.

I’m not sure if the silica gel would lower relative humidity below recommended levels and if the atmospheric pressure sandwiching the storage sleeve against the disc could cause the sleeve to stick to the disc.

**Disclaimer**: Obviously I won’t rely on this working for sure for 10 or 20 years, it would just be one of several copies saved on different types of storage mediums, gradually being replaced with copies on new storage mediums over the years.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What medium should be used for long term, high volume, data storage (archival)?](https://superuser.com/questions/374609/what-medium-should-be-used-for-long-term-high-volume-data-storage-archival)

Comment: @Giacomo1968 It does not. I have a very specific question that's not answered in the answers to this other overly broad question.

Comment: The problem with your question is you need to assume a high level of trust on the part of the Blu-ray disc manufacturers. Whatever they say on the package, what exactly would you do if 10 to 20 years from now you take one of these Blu-ray discs and they don’t work? Such a disc rot or the plastic decaying or the glue used to keep the layers in place fails? Yes, Blu-ray disc manufacturers make all kinds of claims but would you trust truly important data to optical media like this? The best course is to take your own advice: “Obviously I won’t rely on this working for sure for 10 or 20 years…”

Comment: @Giacomo1968 No storage medium is 100% reliable. Should I just give up and memorize everything that I truly need?

Comment: I have files that go back several decades using the methods I posted. Files still good.

Comment: That's at least partly a bad idea. Read what the [Canadian Conservation Institute is writing](https://www.canada.ca/en/conservation-institute/services/conservation-preservation-publications/canadian-conservation-institute-notes/longevity-recordable-cds-dvds.html) - Also you'd need to study how and if silica gel & their packaging interacts with the BD

Comment: @Nobody I never said that. But you yourself say, “Obviously I won’t rely on this working for sure for 10 or 20 years, it would just be one of several copies saved on different types of storage mediums, gradually being replaced with copies on new storage mediums over the years.” I don’t use optical storage nowadays for any reason. I simply upgrade storage every few years or so. And USB flash drives are really cheap so the idea of dealing with optical media hassles nowadays seems masochistic.

Comment: @1NN Excellent link! Great detail and easy to read as well.

Answer (score 0):

An old and archived article
[Blu-Ray Technology](https://web.archive.org/web/20060621131455/http://optical.com/optical_storage/blu-ray.php)
said:

> Blu-ray media like all commercial optical media will have a **50+year shelf life**. The media format can be either MO or WORM. A long shelf life with WORM capabilities make this media perfect for archiving of mandatory compliant data, Medical Images, Video, Document Imaging and number of other near line archival uses. Because of Blu-ray random access capabilities it is also better suited for small files than our tape technology libraries.

You should take the same precautions as for CD/DVD - no extreme
temperatures or humidity. I don't really think that all the wrappings you
mentioned will help. Don't overdo it.