# How to easily access data on ZFS drive connected directly to Windows PC in case of NAS failure?

Tags: windows, nas, zfs

I am aware of the question [Access a ZFS volume in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/289189/access-a-zfs-volume-in-windows). However it is 12 years old. There are some newer answers, however, they are not really clear.

I am setting up TrueNAS on an old PC for a small business and it's all just absolutely amassing. We have 2 storage disks, 2 boot disks so that is enough redundancy for disk failure, however if the PC itself fails, it would mean that employees would have to stop working until it's replaced. That's not a very happy scenario, so it would be nice if it was possible to just take one of the storage drives out, connect it to one of the office Windows PCs and share the files from it temporarily. In case of emergency this might have to be done by someone not very familiar with using virtual machines, linux or command line tools.

Is there a solution for this scenario? Is there a way to easily use ZFS on Windows(in case of emergency, possibly with limited functionality) with some pre-installed tools? What would be the process?

[OpenZFS on Windows](https://openzfsonwindows.org/) seems to be the tool for this, however usage of it seems to be a bit complex. Is there any easier solutions? If not, how would one just access everything on a disk using OpenZFS on Windows?

Comment: I hope this is distinct enough so it doesn't get closed as a duplicate. Even if nobody answers, I would share the solution if I manage to find it on my own eventually, hopefully in more detail than the answers to the mentioned question.

Comment: The 12-years old post has answers dating up to 2022 and basically lists all the possibilities that exist even today. You should read all the answers.

Comment: It points in a direction of a solution with external links, but I would argue, it's not a full solution provided in the answer. I would have posted an answer eventually detailing a specific easy to follow way to just install stuff and set it up so inexperienced user can follow. My case is specific - I need a way for inexperienced user to be able to just plug a drive in and see everything on it. I would think that's a bit different than accessing ZFS volume in Windows in general. Now I am just going to have to make a PDF document detailing the workflow for myself and colleagues in the future...

Comment: The positive action would be to add an answer in the linked post, if you have worked out a better method.

Comment: That way I loose the chance of getting help with it. :D But sure.